# What is the max possible supply for a new cryptocurrency on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum

Would it theoretically be the [Javascript Max Safe Integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)?

Comment: What does Javascript have to do with it??? Since the largest unsigned integer type is `uint256`, the max integer value is `2 ^ 256 - 1`.

Comment: How hard would it be to create a coin with 2 ^ 256 - 1 supply?

Comment: That's a totally different question, so you might want to post it separately. In any case, it seems to consist of two unrelated questions - how hard would it be to create a coin (which is the main question IMO), and how to set the supply to maximum (which, if I understand correctly, is just one line of code once you complete the first part - something like `uint256 supply = ~0`).

Answer (score 2):

Tokens on the Ethereum blockchain are normally stored inside an ERC20 compliant smart contract. Inside this contract the balance of each account is held inside a mapping from addresses to balances, as is explained quite well in [this article](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/understanding-erc-20-token-contracts-a809a7310aa5). The total supply ([as shown here](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20Interface.sol#L17)) is stored in a state variable:

```
uint256 public totalSupply;
```

The theoretically largest value that can be stored in this variable is `2**256 - 1`.